# SQL select for average from another table

Tags: sql, select, average

I spent a lot of time building this select, but Im not able to solve it. I have 2 tables. First table is called car and has PK (primary key) id_car and another columns name and so on. Second table is called rating and has colums id_rating (PK), id_car (FK) and rating_value (integer). As you suspect, one car can have more than one ranting. I want to select all cars and I want to know average rating to each car. Finally, I want to order the result by this average desc. I was trying things like this:

```
    SELECT id_car, name, average
    FROM car C, rating R 
    WHERE C.id_car = R.id_car 
    ORDER BY (average) (
        SELECT AVG(rating_value) AS average 
        FROM rating R
        WHERE C.id_car = R.id_car)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `SQL Server`; Also I suggest you to use `JOIN` instead of `WHERE table1, table2..`

```
SELECT C.id_car, name, AVG(rating_value) AS average
FROM car C JOIN rating R 
      ON C.id_car = R.id_car
GROUP By C.id_car, name
ORDER BY average DESC
```

Comment: Just to add more information: Use LEFT JOIN if you want to include those cars which are not rated yet.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta +1 for that :)

Answer (score 2):

This implements the aggregate function `AVG()` and then a `GROUP BY` the car id and name:

```
select c.id_car, c.name, avg(r.rating_value) aver
from car c
left join rating r
  on c.id_car = r.id_car
group by c.id_car, c.name
order by aver desc
```

Using a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) will include all cars in the result even those which have no yet been rated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.name, AVG(R.rating_value)
FROM car C, rating R 
WHERE C.id_car = R.id_car
GROUP BY C.name
ORDER BY AVG(R.rating_value) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT c.id_car, c.name,avg(r.rating_value) as rating   
FROM car c
 join  rating r 
 on c.id_car = r.id_car   
group by r.id_car 
order by rating
```